# Get an error Remove-Item : Cannot bind parameter 'ErrorAction' after deactivating conda environment

Tags: powershell, anaconda, conda

On Windows 7, Anaconda 2019.10, python 3.11.0 hcf16a7b_0_cpython conda-forge
After activating the env and then deactivating in powershell it I get this error:

```
Remove-Item : Cannot bind parameter 'ErrorAction'. Cannot convert value 'Ignore' to type 'System.Man
agement.Automation.ActionPreference" due to invalid enum values. Specify one of the following list values
clear and try again. The following enumeration values ​​are possible: "SilentlyContinue, Stop, Continue, Inquire".
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pcraster\etc\conda\deactivate.d\gdal-deactivate.ps1:1 pos:39
+ remove-item ENV:GDAL_DATA -ErrorAction <<<<  Ignore
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Same error for position 46
```

What should I fix here?

Comment: The error message implies that it is PowerShell _version 2_ that's running the code. `Ignore` was introduced in v3.

Comment: Can I upgrade it on Windows 7?

Comment: You should be able to, yes: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616